# Bubblesort random Array Java

Tags: java, sorting, bubble-sort

I'm very new to java and have been playing around with sorting algorithms. I have the following code working for a set array. I was just wondering what I'd need to change to get it to sort arrays of randoms lengths and integers. I guess the answer is pretty obvious any help is appreciated!

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   int number[]={8,5,3,2,9};

   int temp;
   boolean fixed=false;
   while(fixed==false){

       fixed=true;

   for(int i=0; i<number.length-1 ; i++){

       if(number[i] > number[i+1]){
       temp = number[i+1];
       number[i+1]=number[i];

       number[i]=temp;
       fixed=false;

       }

    }
   }
   for(int i=0; i<number.length; i++)
       System.out.println(number[i]);

    }

}
```

Comment: What is the question again?

Comment: Hi sorry im just looking to change the array so that it can deal with an inputted array rather than a set one in the code. Sorry if it wasnt clear

Comment: "What I'd need to change" is vague - the most straightforward answer is that you'd need to read the array length and contents from the user input, but that probably isn't the answer you're looking for, so perhaps you could be more specific.

Comment: I like how your question has nothing to do with bubble sort. But you can call your class with int parameters which get mapped to the String[] args. So calling "java YourClassName 1 2 3" will leave you with args = ["1", "2", "3"] which you then can easily cast to integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mean, your algorithm would work regardless of the array's length. About how to generate such arrays, you could do this:

```
int n = Math.random()*10000 + 1; //so its never 0.
int number[] = new int[n];

for(int i=0;i<n;i++) number[i]=Math.random()*10000;
```

Everything else stays the same :).

EDIT: You commented on the question that you'd rather generate the array by taking an input from the keyboard. You can do that by using a scanner.

```
Scanner scanIn = new Scanner(System.in);

do{
    int n = scanIn.nextInt();
} while (n<1);

int number[] = new int[n];   

for(int i=0;i<n;i++) number[i] = scanIn.nextInt();

scanIn.close();
```

Comment: You're welcome! Make sure to mark the answer as correct if it helped you. Also, bear in mind that you could implement much more control on what's the user's input, like, this code doesn't behave properly if I enter a letter instead of a number.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is probably a method to extract your bubblesort to. Please note that this method changes the input array and does not return a new array.

```
private static void bubblesort(int[] array) {
    int temp;
    boolean fixed = false;
    while (!fixed) {
        fixed = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
            if (array[i] > array[i + 1]) {
                temp = array[i + 1];
                array[i + 1] = array[i];
                array[i] = temp;
                fixed = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can then call it using different approaches.

Fixed size array:

```
// fixed size array
int number[] = {8, 5, 3, 2, 9};
bubblesort(number);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(number));
```

Read numbers from `System.in`.

```
// read from sys.in like "2 6 4"
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
String line = s.nextLine();
int[] parsedInts = Arrays.stream(line.split("\\s+")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();

bubblesort(parsedInts);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parsedInts));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can the use Scanner Class in java and need to import java.util.Scanner class

```
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the array length :");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int number[] = new int[n];

        System.out.println("Enter the numbers :");
        for(int i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
            number[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
```